# Difference Equation Solving

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is This Equation solvable , For T(r)   Which is the r'th term

T(r+1) = k.T(r) + c;
If solving is possible, please help with the Method..
Thanks!

Comment: make the Ansatz $$T(r)=q^n$$

Comment: It is not at all a difference equation, but a sequence, more precisely an arithmetico-geometric sequence. See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) for a method of solution.

Comment: Oh. Thanks.   But i dont understand how do i find T(r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume $T_0=a$, apply the formula for the first values of $r$ to see a pattern.

You should get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 r & T_r \\
 0 & a \\
 1 & a k+c \\
 2 & a k^2+c k+c \\
 3 & a k^3+c k^2+c k+c \\
 4 & a k^4+c k^3+c k^2+c k+c \\
 5 & a k^5+c k^4+c k^3+c k^2+c k+c
\end{array}
\right)$$ Do you see it ?

Comment: Yes!, Thanks A Lot!